# Dart Rx remove await

Tags: flutter, dart, rxjs, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am learning rx/dart at the moment. But I am struggeling. Is there any way to make this property synchronized? The `await currentUser()` forces me to do make the property `async` that. But I need some kind of hack, because this part of an interface I can't change. And I don't want to use adapter pattern.

The property should return `Stream<User>`. Any way to achive this?

```
Future<Stream<User>> get onUserOrAuthStateChanged async {
    return authentication.onAuthStateChanged
        .asyncMap<User>((authenticationUser) async {
      return await _retrieveUserFromAuthenticationUser(authenticationUser);
    }).concatWith([
      await currentUser() == null
          ? Stream.empty()
          : userRepository.getStream((await currentUser()).id).skip(1)
    ]);
  }
```

**Edit:** Also `authenticationUser` could be used instead of `await currentUser()`. Like this:

```
Stream<User> get onUserOrAuthStateChanged {
        AuthenticationUser currentAuthenticationUser;
        return authentication.onAuthStateChanged
            .asyncMap<User>((authenticationUser) async {
          currentAuthenticationUser = authenticationUser;
          return await _retrieveUserFromAuthenticationUser(authenticationUser);
        }).concatWith([
          currentAuthenticationUser == null
              ? Stream.empty()
              : userRepository.getStream(currentAuthenticationUser.uid).skip(1)
        ]);
      }
```

With this approach, I get rid of the async, but currentAuthenticationUser is always `null` when the `concatWith` method get's executed, because the assignment happens not synchronized after the `concatWith` `currentAuthenticationUser = authenticationUser;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
Stream<User> get onUserOrAuthStateChanged {
    return authentication.onAuthStateChanged.switchMap((authenticationUser) =>
        authenticationUser == null
            ? Stream.value(null)
            : userRepository.getStream(authenticationUser.uid));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can use the new `await for` syntax instead of RxDart:

```dart
Stream<UserProfile> get user$ async* {
  await for (final currentUser in _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged) {
    if (currentUser != null) {
      await for (final user in getUserStreamFromId(currentUser.uid)) {
        yield UserProfile.fromFirestore(user);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think `await for` works like a `switchMap`, I have created a [gist](https://dartpad.dev/f3be917dea2eeea883db5a144cb93036) to test it.

You can let the `Provider` manage the caching for you if you want the latest value.

```dart
...
StreamProvider(
  create: (context) => userRepo.user$,
),
...
```

This is the Flutter way to do it. Then it is pretty easy to access it in the children:

```dart
final user = context.watch<UserProfile>();
...
```

**Update**

It is probably a better idea to switch, because the dart `await for` API does an exhaust map instead:

```dart
  Stream<UserProfile> get user$ {
    return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.switchMap((currentUser) async* {
      if (currentUser != null) {
        await for (final user in getUserStreamFromId(currentUser.uid)) {
          yield UserProfile.fromFirestore(user);
        }
      } else {
        yield null;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Good insight that `await for` is equivalent to a `switchMap`. From your gist, it does appear that this is the case.

Comment: It does an `exhaustMap` as I pointed out in the update, so it never ends until the source ends. It is only useful if it is the last stream and you do not care about closing it before it ends. Use `switchMap`

Comment: My bad, overlooked that line. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stream.fromFuture()` to convert the `Future` to a `Stream`.

These are some pseudocode options, as I don't fully know your code and neither I tried to compile this, am just typing it here from memory.

```dart
: userRepository.getStream((Stream.fromFuture(await currentUser())).id).skip(1)
```

```dart
: userRepository.getStream((Stream.fromFuture(currentUser().map((u) => u.id)))).skip(1)
```

Comment: How would you apply this to the above scenario? Still don't get it quite

Comment: "The getter 'id' isn't defined for the class 'Stream<User>'."

This doesn't work.

Comment: Map it so you get the `id`, I am not aware of your classes so I just did a quick pseudocode. Something like `.map((u) => u.id).skip(1)`.

Comment: Or just place an `await` before the `currentUser`

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to accept and vote for it.